# How to make wordpress admin menu collapsed by default?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress

I hope you all have seen wordpress admin panel. We have option at the end of menu to collapse or expand the menu.

If you click on collapse the menu gets collapsed and that settings gets saved ( I don't know where ) but if you login again you will see the same collapsed menu..

Where are they storing that data ??? 
I want to make admin menu to be shown collapsed by default how do i do that ?

Edit : I think the file wp-admin/js/common.js is responsible for that.. 
you can view the file here http://phpcrossref.com/xref/wordpress/wp-admin/js/common.js.txt

I think I got the code which is responsible for that, but I am new to js. The code is as follows :

```
$('#collapse-menu').on('click.collapse-menu', function() {
    var body = $( document.body ), respWidth, state;

    // reset any compensation for submenus near the bottom of the screen
    $('#adminmenu div.wp-submenu').css('margin-top', '');

    if ( window.innerWidth ) {
        // window.innerWidth is affected by zooming on phones
        respWidth = Math.max( window.innerWidth, document.documentElement.clientWidth );
    } else {
        // IE < 9 doesn't support @media CSS rules
        respWidth = 961;
    }

    if ( respWidth && respWidth < 960 ) {
        if ( body.hasClass('auto-fold') ) {
            body.removeClass('auto-fold').removeClass('folded');
            setUserSetting('unfold', 1);
            setUserSetting('mfold', 'o');
            state = 'open';
        } else {
            body.addClass('auto-fold');
            setUserSetting('unfold', 0);
            state = 'folded';
        }
    } else {
        if ( body.hasClass('folded') ) {
            body.removeClass('folded');
            setUserSetting('mfold', 'o');
            state = 'open';
        } else {
            body.addClass('folded');
            setUserSetting('mfold', 'f');
            state = 'folded';
        }
    }

    $( document ).trigger( 'wp-collapse-menu', { state: state } );
});
```

Comment: Just download a plugin for that.  simple enough.

Comment: What you've shown us here is the click function--that is, what happens when you click the links. What we need is the initialization function or a template--how the menu is set up initially.

Comment: You'll need to find where the template uses the `auto-fold` and `folded` classes, and make sure that the default is `folded` on page load. I can't say more until you find out where that is done.

Comment: @ntgCleaner Which plugin ?? you know any ??

Comment: @isherwood you can have a look at the wordpress admin demo here    https://demos1.softaculous.com/WordPress/wp-login.php  username: admin password: pass

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Finally I found the answer :

We just need to add class 'folded' in body tag to make admin menu folded. I added the class in body tag using JavaScript : document.body.className+=' folded';

here is the complete code that I added to the functions.php ( you can add that to your plugin also )

the code :=

```
function custom_admin_js() {
    echo "<script type='text/javascript' > 
document.body.className+=' folded';                 
</script>";

}
add_action('admin_footer', 'custom_admin_js');
```

and it worked :)

Answer (score 8):

The above solution is a good way to do. But in this solution, we could get to see some flashes, where until the page is loaded and script executes if it is painted, then we might be able to see it open.

I came up with this solution via backend after digging into some core files.

```
add_filter("admin_body_class", "my_folded_menu", 10, 1);

function my_folded_menu($classes){
    return $classes." folded";
}
```

What this does is the same thing, it adds class. Just that it does it from the backend instead of the frontend.

Comment: Brilliant!  This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: I tried everything to remove the WP NAV menu from only a particular page because I am using the page to show scan results. You cannot use CSS to hide the WP NAV menus without getting a brief flash of the autogenerated load-styles.php scripts. I used your code and gave it a preg_match condition and it works beautifully to only collapse the WP Nav menu on a specific page:  if ( is_admin() && preg_match( '/page=bulletproof-security.*mscan-scan-status.php/', esc_html($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) ) ) {
  return $classes." folded";
 }

Answer (score -1):

You'll need to find where the template uses the `auto-fold` and `folded` classes, and make sure that the default is `folded` on page load. I can't say more until you find out where that is done.